# Big O of append in Golang

Tags: go, append, complexity-theory, slice

What is the complexity of Go's builtin `append` function? What about string concatenation using `+`?

I'd like to remove an element from a slice by appending two slices excluding that element, ex. http://play.golang.org/p/RIR5fXq-Sf

```
nums := []int{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}
fmt.Println(append(nums[:4], nums[5:]...))

=> [0 1 2 3 5 6 7]
```

http://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#append says that if the destination has sufficient capacity, then that slice is `resliced`. I'm hoping that "reslicing" is a constant time operation. I'm also hoping the same applies to string concatenation using `+`.

Comment: Some ref on the behavior:  http://criticalindirection.com/2016/02/17/slice-with-a-pinch-of-salt/

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This all depends on the actual implementation used, but I'm basing this on the standard Go as well as gccgo.

**Slices**

Reslicing means changing an integer in a struct (a slice is a struct with three fields: length, capacity and pointer to backing memory).

If the slice does not have sufficient capacity, append will need to allocate new memory and copy the old one over. For slices with <1024 elements, it will double the capacity, for slices with >1024 elements it will increase it by factor 1.25.

**Strings**

Since strings are immutable, each string concatenation with `+` will create a new string, which means copying the old one. So if you're doing it N times in a loop, you will allocate N strings and copy memory around N times.

Comment: Thanks! What about passing a slice of uint8 to the `string` function? Is that `O(1)` or `O(n)`? (standard Go implementation)

Comment: O(n). Slices are mutable, strings are not → it has to copy the data.

Comment: In other words, appending an element to a slice is amortized O(1).

Comment: Is this documented anywhere official?

Comment: @Bryan As pointed out in this post http://www.reddit.com/r/golang/comments/39w6e2/stackgo_a_slicebased_implementation_of_a_simple/ you can find this behaviour hardcoded here http://golang.org/src/runtime/slice.go#L59

Comment: Re strings: using the concatenation operator actually has O(n^2) complexity. Perhaps that's what you meant with your example when you mentioned copying data around but I don't think this part was clear enough in your answer.

Comment: I think this should be clearly described as part of the class contract in the slice documentation. For example the Java ArrayList explicitly states that add() is amortized constant time, so all implementations must conform to that or they're in violation of the API.