# Efficient appending to a variable-length container of strings (Golang)

Tags: go, containers, slice

The problem:

I need to apply multiple regexes to each line of a big log file (like several GB long) , gather non-empty matches and put them all in an array (for serialization and sending it over the network).

Slices are not much help if answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17332227/big-o-of-append-in-golang) holds:

> If the slice does not have sufficient capacity, append will need to allocate new memory and copy the old one over. For slices with <1024 elements, it will double the capacity, for slices with >1024 elements it will increase it by factor 1.25.

Since there can be literally hundreds of thousands of regex matches, I can't really predict the length / capacity of a slice. I can't make it too big either "just in case" bc this will waste memory (or will it? if memory allocator is smart enough not to allocate too much memory that is not written into, maybe I could use a huge slice capacity without much harm?).

So I'm thinking about following alternative:

1. have a doubly-linked list of matches (http://golang.org/pkg/container/list/)
2. calc its length (will `len()` work?)
3. preallocate a slice of this capacity
4. copy string pointers to this slice

Is there a less laborious way of achieving this goal in Go (append with ~ O(1) append complexity)?

(golang newbie here of course)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`append()`'s *average* (amortized) cost is already O(1) because it grows the array by a percentage each time. As the array gets larger, growing it gets costlier but proportionately rarer. A 10M-item slice will be 10x more expensive to grow than a 1M-item slice, but since the extra capacity we're allocating is proportional to the size, it'll also be 10x as many `append(slice, item)` calls until the next time it grows. The increasing cost and decreasing frequency of reallocations cancel out, leaving the average cost constant, i.e., O(1).

The same idea applies other languages' dynamically-sized arrays, too: Microsoft's `std::vector` implementation apparently grows the array by 50% each time, for example. Amortized O(1) doesn't mean you pay nothing for allocations, only that you continue paying at the same average rate as your array gets bigger.

On my laptop, I could run a million `slice = append(slice, someStaticString)`s in 77ms. One reason it's quick, which siritinga noted below, is that "copying" the string to enlarge the array is really just copying the string header (a pointer/length pair), not copying the contents. 100,000 string headers is still under 2MB to copy, not a big deal compared to the other quantities of data you're working with.

`container/list` turned out ~3x slower for me in a microbenchmark; linked-list append is also constant time, of course, but I imagine `append` has a lower constant because it can usually just write to a couple words of memory and not allocate a list item, etc. The timing code won't work in the Playground but you can copy this locally and run it to see yourself: http://play.golang.org/p/uYyMScmOjX

Sometimes, you can usefully pre-allocate space to avoid reallocations/copies (in this example, using `make([]string, 0, 1000000)` takes the runtime from ~77ms to ~10ms), but, of course, often-to-usually just you don't have enough info about the expected data size and so on to eke out worthwhile gains, and you're better off leaving it to the built-in algorithm.

---

But you're asking a more specific question here about a `grep`-like application (and thanks for asking a detailed question with context). For that, bottom-line recommendation is that if you're searching gigs of logs, it's probably best to avoid buffering the whole output in RAM at all.

You could write something to stream the results as a single function: `logparser.Grep(in io.Reader, out io.Writer, patterns []regexp.Regexp)`; you could alternatively make `out` a `chan []byte` or `func(match []byte) (err error)` if you don't want the code that sends results to be too enmeshed with the grep code.

(On `[]byte` vs. `string`: a `[]byte` seems to do the job here and avoids `[]byte`<=>`string` conversions when you do I/O, so I'd prefer that. I don't know what all you're doing, though, and if you need `string` it's fine.)

If you *do* keep the whole match list in RAM, be aware that keeping around a reference to part of a big string or byte slice keeps the whole source string/slice from being garbage collected. So if you go that route, then counterintuitively you may actually *want* to copy matches to avoid keeping all of the source log data in RAM.

Comment: Given the volumes of data tb handled I have to limit the number of lines to scan in one run (reasons should be obvious: averaging out I/O load, CPU load and resident set size, i.e. preventing big load peaks) so I do not have to stream really. But what is more important here to me is that I do not really understand what you mean that if I overflow 1M rows the next op will not be 1.25M row allocation + copying that 1M rows? See next comment for calculation.

Comment: In Python: a=1; cumul=0. Then `for i in range(10): print 'rows %.2f cumul %.2f' % (a, cumul),; cumul +=a; a=a*1.25`. Result: rows 1.00 cumul 0.00 rows 1.25 cumul 1.00 rows 1.56 cumul 2.25 rows 1.95 cumul 3.81 rows 2.44 cumul 5.77 rows 3.05 cumul 8.21 rows 3.81 cumul 11.26 rows 4.77 cumul 15.07 rows 5.96 cumul 19.84 rows 7.45 cumul 25.80. So if I start with 1M rows slice and have 8 million matches that would require copying slice 10 times and have total of 25M rows copied. That's not a very good cost in comparison to say linked list..

Comment: I think that a slice of strings is internally a slice of pointers to strings, in the sense that extending the slice will not actually copy the strings, just the pointers to the strings, so each entry will be 4 or 8 bytes (depending on the system architecture), so it should be fast.

Comment: Alternatively, if you want to serialize the strings, you can use `bytes`: http://play.golang.org/p/RiRqFLg8re I don't know if it is faster than the slice of strings, I think it is a slice of bytes so possibly it will be slower than slices of strings, but faster than concatenating strings. It is another option.

Comment: @JohnDoe--I tried `container/list` and it didn't turn out faster: http://play.golang.org/p/LSX9zS3VVt has the code (the timing parts won't work in Playground but you can download and run to get your own results).

Comment: One more thought: you can implement `append()`'s logic yourself and grow the list more aggressively (e.g., 2x not 1.25x) if you're OK with trading higher RAM use for fewer copies. You would want to benchmark and make sure that really does help, though. Also, read peterSO's answer for perspective--`append()` won't be the bottleneck here.

Comment: @user2714852: WOW thank you for this, this was enlightening - I ran several tests and I got similar results even for progressively bigger numbers of iterations, i.e. run time for linked list to run time of append were similar. At one point it seems that linked list either exhausted memory or clogged CPU while append finished in reasonable time. Well, you learn smth counterintuitive every day it seems.

Answer (score 3):

I tried to distill your question into a very simple example.

Since there can be "hundreds of thousands of regex matches", I did a large initial allocation of 1 M (1024 * 1024) entries for the `matches` slice capacity. A slice is a reference type. A slice header 'struct' has length, a capacity, and a pointer for a total of 24 (3 * 8) bytes on a 64-bit OS. The initial allocation for a slice of 1 M entries is therefore only 24 (24 * 1) MB. If there are more than 1 M entries, a new slice with capacity of 1.25 (1 + 1 / 4) M entries will be allocated and the existing 1 M slice header entries (24 MB) will be copied to it.

In summary, you can avoid much of the the overhead of many `append`s by initially over allocating the slice capacity. The bigger memory problem is all the data that is saved and referenced for each match. The far bigger CPU time problem is the time taken to perform the `regexp.FindAll`'s.

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "regexp"
)

var searches = []*regexp.Regexp{
    regexp.MustCompile("configure"),
    regexp.MustCompile("unknown"),
    regexp.MustCompile("PATH"),
}

var matches = make([][]byte, 0, 1024*1024)

func main() {
    logName := "config.log"
    log, err := os.Open(logName)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    defer log.Close()
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(log)
    for scanner.Scan() {
        line := scanner.Bytes()
        for _, s := range searches {
            for _, m := range s.FindAll(line, -1) {
                matches = append(matches, append([]byte(nil), m...))
            }
        }
    }
    if err := scanner.Err(); err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, err)
    }
    // Output matches
    fmt.Println(len(matches))
    for i, m := range matches {
        fmt.Println(string(m))
        if i >= 16 {
            break
        }
    }
}
```