# Golang: appending slices with or w/o allocation

Tags: go, append, slice

Go's `append()` function only allocates new slice data, when the capacity of the given slice is not sufficient (see also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28143457/802833). This can lead to unexpected behavior (at least for me as a golang newbie):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {

    a1 := make([][]int, 3)
    a2 := make([][]int, 3)
    b := [][]int{{1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 2}, {3, 3, 3}}
    common1 := make([]int, 0)
    common2 := make([]int, 0, 12) // provide sufficient capacity
    common1 = append(common1, []int{10, 20}...)
    common2 = append(common2, []int{10, 20}...)

    idx := 0
    for _, k := range b {
        a1[idx] = append(common1, k...) // new slice is allocated
        a2[idx] = append(common2, k...) // no allocation
        idx++
    }

    fmt.Println(a1)
    fmt.Println(a2) // surprise!!!
}
```

output:

> [[10 20 1 1 1] [10 20 2 2 2] [10 20 3 3 3]]
>
> [[10 20 3 3 3] [10 20 3 3 3] [10 20 3 3 3]]

https://play.golang.org/p/8PEqFxAsMt

So, what ist the (idomatic) way in Go to force allocation of new slice data or more precisely to make sure that the slice argument to `append()` remains unchanged?

Comment: The "problem" is less the behaviour of append but your code which is needless complex.

Comment: @Volker The example has been extracted out of a bigger context. If I need just to append the shown slices, there indeed is a simpler way :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanx for your feedback.

So the solution to gain control of the memory allocation is to do it explicitely (which remembers me that Go is a more a system language than other (scripting) langs):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {

    a1 := make([][]int, 3)
    a2 := make([][]int, 3)
    b := [][]int{{1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 2}, {3, 3, 3}}
    common1 := make([]int, 0)
    common2 := make([]int, 0, 12) // provide sufficient capacity
    common1 = append(common1, []int{10, 20}...)
    common2 = append(common2, []int{10, 20}...)

    idx := 0
    for _, k := range b {
        a1[idx] = append(common1, k...) // new slice is allocated
        
        a2[idx] = make([]int, len(common2), len(common2)+len(k))
        copy(a2[idx], common2)      // copy & append could probably be
        a2[idx] = append(a2[idx], k...) // combined into a single copy step
        
        idx++
    }

    fmt.Println(a1)
    fmt.Println(a2)
}
```

output:

> [[10 20 1 1 1] [10 20 2 2 2] [10 20 3 3 3]]
>
> [[10 20 1 1 1] [10 20 2 2 2] [10 20 3 3 3]]

https://play.golang.org/p/Id_wSZwb84

Comment: About explicit memory allocation... That's yes and no. A common idiom to append to a slice is to just not bother and do `s = append(s, e1, e2, ...)` -- so that Go will make sure the backing array will be reallocated if appending would require it.  This frees you from thinking about memory management *unless* you have other slices pointing to the same data (i.e. you've sliced the original slice before appending to it).  But that's a good tradeoff: it makes the simple case simple and the complex cases possible.

Comment: One more point regarding that idiom I've referred to, is that sometimes you know your slice will have *at least* N element (or may be more) or *at most* N elements. In either case it's possible to do a micro optimization and allocate the slice with length 0 and capacity `N` via `s := make([]T, 0, N)`. In the former case you will be guaranteed that appending the first `N` elements won't reallocate; in the second case you may waste some space trading this for appending speed. In either case, *please don't opmimize before you've profiled!*

Answer (score 9):

You might maintain a wrong idea of how slices work in Go.

When you append elements to a slice, the call to `append()` returns a new slice.  If reallocation did not happen, both slice values — the one you called `append()` on and the one it returned back — share the same backing array *but* they will have different lengths; observe:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    a := make([]int, 0, 10)
    b := append(a, 1, 2, 3)
    c := append(a, 4, 3, 2)
    fmt.Printf("a=%#v\nb=%#v\nc=%#v\n", a, b, c)
}
```

outputs:

```
a=[]int{}
b=[]int{4, 3, 2}
c=[]int{4, 3, 2}
```

So, `len(a) == 0`, `len(b) == 3`, `len(c) == 3`, and the second call to `append()` owerwrote what the first one did because all the slices share the same underlying array.

As to reallocation of the backing array, [the spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Appending_and_copying_slices) is clear:

> If the capacity of s is not large enough to fit the additional values, append allocates a new, sufficiently large underlying array that fits both the existing slice elements and the additional values. Otherwise, append re-uses the underlying array.

From this, it follows that:

1. `append()` never copies the underlying storage if the capacity of the slice being appeneded to is sufficient.
2. If there's not enough capacity, the array will be reallocated.

That is, given a slice `s` to which you want to append `N` elements, the reallocation won't be done iff `cap(s) - len(s) ≥ N`.

Hence I suspect your problem is not about unexpected reallocation results but rather about the *concept* of slices as implemented in Go. The code idea to absorb is that `append()` *returns the resulting slice value,* which you're supposed to be using after the call *unless* you fully understand the repercussions.

I recommend starting with [this](http://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals) to fully understand them.

Comment: Thanx for pointing to the blog post. So, in order to achieve the desired (and reproducible) behavior, I could write: `b := make([]int, len(a), len(a)+3); copy(b, a); b = append(b, []int{1, 2, 3})`

Comment: @kirk If you're appending to a slice `s`, always *always* write `s = append(s, value)`, so essentially "yes".

Comment: @kirk, yes, to make sure appending N elements won't reallocate the backing array, create a slice with enough capacity to hold your current data *plus* N, copy existing slice over to the new one and then append.