# append() possibly modify the original slice (2d slice recursion)

Tags: go, pointers, recursion, slice

(The coding problem is to generate all solutions of combinations that sum to target with unlimited number of times of each ele in candidates arr.)

A 2d `[][]int` slice `theList` is passed by reference in a recursion that gets appended `[]int` (`tmpCombo`), but after getting appended, one of the elements gets modified, `[3 3 3 3 3 3]` changes to `[3 3 3 3 3 2]`. so I have to make a copy of `tmpCombo` before doing the `append()`. Does `append(arr, ele)` changes the original `arr` slice? If so, I should've observed more original `arr` getting modified, but this happens only once. So I actually am fairly confused how this slice `append()` works.

https://go.dev/play/p/PH10SxiF7A5

> ...
> theList: [.... [3 3 3 3 3 3]]
> theList: [.... [3 3 3 3 3 2] [3 3 3 3 2 2 2]]

(I also tried to do a for loop and keep appending to a slice, that original slice didn't get changed at all...)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sort"
)

func combinationSum(candidates []int, target int) [][]int {
    sort.Sort(sort.Reverse(sort.IntSlice(candidates)))

    var theList [][]int
    var tmpCombo []int
    rCombo(candidates, target, 0, tmpCombo, &theList)

    return theList
}

func rCombo(candidates []int, target int, index int, tmpCombo []int, theList *[][]int) {
    if index >= len(candidates) {
        fmt.Println("index:", index)
        return
    }
    // fmt.Println(target)
    if candidates[index] > target {
        rCombo(candidates, target, index+1, tmpCombo, theList)
        return
    }

    for i:=index; i<len(candidates); i++ {
        if candidates[i] < target {
                rCombo(candidates, target-candidates[i], i, append(tmpCombo, candidates[i]), theList)
        } else if candidates[i] == target {

            // NOTE: simply append tmpCombo will give weird output [3 3 3 3 3 3] changed to [3 3 3 3 3 2].              
            *theList = append(*theList,  append(tmpCombo, target))

            // cpyCombo := make([]int, len(tmpCombo))
            // copy(cpyCombo, tmpCombo)
            // *theList = append(*theList,  append(cpyCombo, target))

            // appended slice didn't change address so tmpCombo was modified
            for i:=0; i<len(*theList); i++ {
                fmt.Printf("%d %p ", (*theList)[i], (*theList)[i])
            }
            fmt.Println()

            // fmt.Println("cc", tmpCombo, candidates[i], append(cpyCombo, candidates[i]), theList )
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    // 2,3,5
    candidates := []int{7,3,2}
    target := 18
    combinationSum(candidates, target)

 // test: this does not change the original s...
// var s []int = make([]int, 6)
// // var x []int

// for i:=0; i<200; i++ {
//  x := append(s, i)
//  fmt.Println(x, s)
// }
}
```

Comment: I am not really sure I understand your question... what is the expected behaviour and what do you see instead? See here for an authoritative description of Go slices https://go.dev/blog/slices-intro

Comment: @DrGo I added the output. The 2d slice gets appended new []int, but why it changed after?

Comment: Are you using the same code as above? AFAICS, you only append to theList when `candidate[i] ==target which is impossible with the shown test values

Comment: @DrGo I added a link and a description of the orig problem.

Comment: Also see this possible duplicate answer: [Concatenate two slices in Go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16248241/concatenate-two-slices-in-go/40036950#40036950)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand it now thanks to this answer illustrating the same issue https://stackoverflow.com/a/28143457/1582790.

Basically if the slice has data stored in one place with specified capacity but has length as a separate attribute... In my case, doing multiple `append(tmpCombo, target)` actually modifies the data in `tmpCombo` because the variable isn't reassigned/updated with new length and the underlying data in the same place gets modified (when not reallocated).

tldr. make sure to pass new copies of the same data with either:

`make()` new slice and `copy()` over (`make()` assigns specific capacity)

or

`append(nil []int, arr...]`. (`append()` may allocate more mem but good for frequent modification)

Answer (score 0):

If you try to append elements past the slice's capacity, append will allocate a new underlying array.

After it does that, changes to the "old" slice will not be reflected in the "new" slice, since they have a different underlying array.

I hope this answers the question