# Different performances in Go slices resize

Tags: go, stack, benchmarking, slice

I'm spending some time experimenting with Go's internals and I ended up writing my own implementation of a [stack](https://github.com/alediaferia/stackgo) using slices.
As correctly pointed out by a reddit user in [this](http://www.reddit.com/r/golang/comments/39w6e2/stackgo_a_slicebased_implementation_of_a_simple/) post and as outlined by another user in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17332227/big-o-of-append-in-golang) Go already tries to optimise slices resize.

Turns out, though, that I rather have performance gains using my own implementation of slice growing rather than sticking with the default one.

This is the structure I use for holding the stack:

```
type Stack struct {
    slice []interface{}
    blockSize int
}

const s_DefaultAllocBlockSize = 20;
```

This is **my own** implementation of the `Push` method

```
func (s *Stack) Push(elem interface{}) {
    if len(s.slice) + 1 == cap(s.slice) {
        slice := make([]interface{}, 0, len(s.slice) + s.blockSize)
        copy(slice, s.slice)
        s.slice = slice
    }

    s.slice = append(s.slice, elem)
}
```

This is a plain implementation

```
func (s *Stack) Push(elem interface{}) {
    s.slice = append(s.slice, elem)
}
```

Running the benchmarks I've implemented using Go's [testing](http://golang.org/pkg/testing/) package my own implementation performs this way:

```
Benchmark_PushDefaultStack  20000000            87.7 ns/op        24 B/op          1 allocs/op
```

While relying on the plain `append` the results are the following

```
Benchmark_PushDefaultStack  10000000           209 ns/op          90 B/op          1 allocs/op
```

The machine I run tests on is an early 2011 Mac Book Pro, 2.3 GHz Intel Core i5 with 8GB of RAM 1333MHz DDR3

**EDIT**
The actual question is: is my implementation really faster than the default append behavior? Or am I not taking something into account?

Comment: And the question is ...?

Comment: @inf LOL, sorry! :) It must have stayed in the keyboard. Just updated the question.

Comment: What's the initial capacity of the slice in the slower example?

Comment: I still wouldn't call that a question. Your performance bench mark is very small minded. Your allocation works better because you're dealing with small data sets. Slices have base 2 growth by default, I would hardly call it optimized and it's really easy to test. The slice is just over allocating a lot here because you're starting with 0 capacity and reallocated in the 0,1,2,4,8,16,32 elements ect and the algorithm doesn't pick up until your set gets big.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal I'd call yours an answer though :) Thank you

Comment: Are you sure your `Push` is correct? I think you are missing to copy the existing values during slice cap growths. If your copy is a noop it will be faster, bit wrong.

Comment: @Volker I'm copying the existing values with `copy(slice, s.slice)`

Comment: @alediaferia: Yes, but your `slice` has length 0, so you don't copy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reading your code, tests, benchmarks, and results it's easy to see that they are flawed. A full code review is beyond the scope of StackOverflow.

One specific bug.

```
// Push pushes a new element to the stack
func (s *Stack) Push(elem interface{}) {
    if len(s.slice)+1 == cap(s.slice) {
        slice := make([]interface{}, 0, len(s.slice)+s.blockSize)
        copy(slice, s.slice)
        s.slice = slice
    }

    s.slice = append(s.slice, elem)
}
```

Should be

```
// Push pushes a new element to the stack
func (s *Stack) Push(elem interface{}) {
    if len(s.slice)+1 == cap(s.slice) {
        slice := make([]interface{}, len(s.slice), len(s.slice)+s.blockSize)
        copy(slice, s.slice)
        s.slice = slice
    }

    s.slice = append(s.slice, elem)
}
```

> [copying
>   slices](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Appending_and_copying_slices)
>
> The function `copy` copies slice elements from a source `src` to a
>   destination `dst` and returns the number of elements copied. The
>   number of elements copied is the minimum of `len(src)` and `len(dst)`.

You copied `0`, you should have copied `len(s.slice)`.

As expected, your Push algorithm is inordinately slow:

```
append:

Benchmark_PushDefaultStack-4     2000000           941 ns/op          49 B/op          1 allocs/op

alediaferia:

Benchmark_PushDefaultStack-4      100000       1246315 ns/op       42355 B/op          1 allocs/op
```

This how `append` works: [append complexity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15702419/append-complexity).

There are other things wrong too. Your benchmark results are often not valid.

Comment: Thank you @peterSO. I'll review my code asap following your hints and will study your links as well. I'm always happy to learn from more experienced engineers.

Comment: I actually changed my implementation here: https://github.com/alediaferia/stackgo/tree/page_based

Your points were all right and it's probably better to set yours as the right answer. Anyway, would you like to review my new code? I'd really appreciate that. Shall we move to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ for this?

Answer (score 3):

I believe your example is faster because you have a fairly small data set and are allocating with an initial capacity of 0. In your version of append you preempt a large amount of allocations by growing the block size more dramatically early (by 20) circumventing the (in this case) expensive reallocs that take you through all those trivially small capacities 0,1,2,4,8,16,32,64 ect

If your data sets were a lot larger this would likely be marginalized by the cost of large copies. I've seen a lot of misuse of slice in Go. The clear performance win is had by making your slice with a reasonable default capacity.

Comment: Just a small correction. I'm allocating with initial capacity of 20 as you can see here: https://github.com/alediaferia/stackgo/blob/master/stackgo.go#L21
Other than that your point makes total sense to me.

Comment: NOTE: The problem is bugs in the program giving invalid results. This answer is wrong.

Comment: @peterSO alright dude... lol. Sorry I didn't reference the spec while explaining that giving the array capacity of 20 circumvents at least 5 reallocs. It's conceptually correct, I don't touch any technical terms so you should probably try being less of a douche bag.