# Does append() in Go run on amortized constant time?

Tags: go

Java's `ArrayList` add method runs in amortized constant time. Same for vector's push_back in C++.

So does `append()` in Go also run on amortized constant time?

Answer (score 0):

see https://blog.golang.org/slices
The answer should be 'yes' as you expect

Comment: [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17332313/6178021)
"... If the slice does not have sufficient capacity, append will need to allocate new memory and copy the old one over ..."
If the copying takes place, the run time would be O(n), not O(1).

Comment: reallocation takes exactly O(n) but no need to reallocate each time, amortized O(1).