# Time complexity for an append function of slice

Tags: go, time-complexity

What is the time complexity of the following function which removes an element from slice?

Is it O(n)? How append function in Go affects time complexity ? (Since following code tries to remove an element the new slice capacity is less than or equal to former slice , i was under the impression that just new slice header only gets created behind the scenes and O(n) would be time complexity).

**The slice that gets passed as parameter to function has capacity, length equal.**

```
// Remove a given element from slice 
func Remove(elementToRemove string, elements []string) []string {
    if govalidator.IsNull(elementToRemove) {
        return elements
    }
    for i := len(elements) - 1; i >= 0; i-- {
        if elements[i] == elementToRemove {
            elements = append(elements[:i], elements[i+1:]...)
            break
        }
    }
    return elements
}
```

Comment: The work done by append in your case (cap > len) is proportionally to the size of what gets appended.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Big O of append in Golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17332227/big-o-of-append-in-golang)